# Using PHP & .htaccess to Create Fancy URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, openwrt

I was wondering if this was a safe way of making page links
I have my error page set to error.php so that catches all 404's
I'm using OpenWRT with uhttpd so I can't use RewriteEngine
This is error.php

```
<?php
$Url = htmlspecialchars(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$NewUrl = str_replace('/', '', $Url);

if($NewUrl === 'SecondPage') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 200');
    include('../Index/Head.php');
    include('../SecondPage/SecondPage.php');
    include('../Index/Foot.php');
    exit();
} else {
?>
<p>
    Error <a href="/">Go Home</a>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

So that when a user enters EG: 127.0.0.1/SecondPage you get a second page and a nice friendly URL
But anything else EG: 127.0.0.1/RandomUrl Will produce a 404
I've tried searching the forums, But everything says I need .htaccess and RewriteEngine (Both of which don't work with uhttpd)

Comment: @JonLin
It's good for me (Directory wise) It's much easier to maintain the code (As index page is only included)

Comment: Depends, what code does a valid page return? Not a 404 I hope.

Comment: By the way, if you do a literal comparisson, there is no need to manipulate your string using functions like `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: How are you telling uhttpd that every request should go through this file? Once you've got that fixed, you can do it yourself (like you did now), or use any of the routing features of existing web applications and frameworks (practically all of them use something like this). The hard part is to get every request to go through a single entrypoint.php.

Comment: @GolezTrol The OP is using the 404 error page.

Comment: @jeroen I've got headers set to 200 on /SecondPage, And care to explain literal comparison?

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm using uhttpd's config file to set the error page to error.php

Comment: `$NewUrl === 'SecondPage'`: It doesn't matter if `$NewUrl` is prepared for html, a database, contains js exploits, etc.: You are comparing it to a string so it is either exactly the same or it is not.

Comment: @jeroen Ah, I get ya, So it can't be anything other than SecondPage EG: SecondPage<script></script> as it's set in the if clause